# Pros/Cons of storing serialized hash vs. key/value database object in ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, key-value-store, activerecord

If I have several objects that each have basically a `Profile`, what I'm using to store random attributes, what are the pros and cons of:

1. Storing a serialized hash in a column for a record, vs.
2. Storing a bunch of key/value objects that `belong_to` the main object.

### Code

Say you have STI records like these:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :as => :profilable
end
class OfficeBuilding < Building; end
class Home < Building; end
class Restaurant < Building; end
```

Each `has_one :profile`

#### Option 1. Serialized Hash

```
class SerializedProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :settings
end

create_table :profiles, :force => true do |t|
  t.string   :name
  t.string   :website
  t.string   :email
  t.string   :phone
  t.string   :type
  t.text     :settings
  t.integer  :profilable_id
  t.string   :profilable_type
  t.timestamp
end
```

#### Option 2. Key/Value Store

```
class KeyValueProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :settings
end

create_table :profiles, :force => true do |t|
  t.string   :name
  t.string   :website
  t.string   :email
  t.string   :phone
  t.string   :type
  t.integer  :profilable_id
  t.string   :profilable_type
  t.timestamp
end

create_table :settings, :force => true do |t|
  t.string   :key
  t.text     :value
  t.integer  :profile_id
  t.string   :profile_type
  t.timestamp
end
```

Which would you choose?

Assume that 99% of the time I won't need to search by the custom `settings`.  Just wondering what the tradeoffs are in terms of performance and the likelihood of future problems.  And the number of custom `settings` will likely be anywhere from 10-50.

I would rather go with the second option, with the settings table, because it follows the ActiveRecord object-oriented conventions.  But I'm wondering if in this kind of situation that would come at too high a performance cost.

Note: I am wondering in terms of RDBMS only.  This would be a perfect fit for MongoDB/Redis/CouchDB/etc. but I want to know purely the pros and cons in terms of SQL.

Comment: You really don't want to store things serialized if you can help it. There's no real speed advantage for retrieval, and disadvantages when it comes to searching and updating. I'm having to work with a system that has a DB record containing XML of about 50 fields from another database stored as a text field. Searching requires using `like` statements and I have to parse and search the XML to get at the data I need. It's a horrible design and WILL go away eventually.

Comment: @the Tin Man: some serious databases, including PostgreSQL are supporting XML data or text column and give ability to search (XPath), index and create views from XML data quite easly. Check: [XML data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html) and [XML functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html)

Comment: @gertas, I would love to use Postgres, but they didn't ask me. Also, even [Postgres says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html#AEN6805) that unless indexed strings are provided, we're still stuck with in-string searching. Once you know what record it is, then you could use XPath to extract data as fields, but I can do that just as easy, or easier, by retrieving the entire XML text and doing it in Ruby or Perl.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem, but finally made the decision.

Hash serialization option makes maintenance problem. It is hard to query, extend or refactor such data - any subtle change needs migration which means reading each record deserializing and serializing back, and depending on refactoring serialization exception may happen.
I tried both binary serialization and JSON - the second is easier to extract and fix but still too much hassle.

Separate settings table is what I'm trying to use now - much easier to maintain. I plan to use [Preferences](http://github.com/pluginaweek/preferences) gem for that which mostly does all abstraction for easy use. I'm not sure if it works with Rails 3 yet - it is small so I can extend it if needed.

**Update Nov 2013**

Recently released Rails 4 supports great new features of PostgreSQL 9.1+ such as **hstore** or **json** column types for your dynamic data sets. Here is an article covering [hstore usage in Rails 4](http://rny.io/rails/postgresql/2013/08/03/custom-fields-in-rails-using-postgresql-hstore.html). Both types support indexing and advanced querying capabilities (Json with Pg 9.3). Hstore is also available to Rails 3 users with [activerecord-postgres-hstore](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore) gem.

I am in the process of migrating some of non critical preference tables in my project to hstores. In migrations I just update table definitions and `execute` one SQL query per table to move the data.

Answer (score 5):

I would recomend just creating a model call Attribute and have each of your objects that need many of them has_many.    Then you don't have to mess around with serialization or anything brittle like that.  If you use the :join syntax you don't have any real performance issues with this.

Serializing data into your RDBMS is almost always unwise. It's more than about queries, it's about the ability to describe and migrate your data (and serialization shatters that ability).

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attributes
end

class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :building
end

create_table :attributes, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer :building_id
  t.string :att_name
  t.string :data
  t.timestamp
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same dilemma you described and ended up going with the key/value table implementation because of the potential maintenance advantages that others mentioned. It's just easier to think through how I could select and update information in separate rows of the database in a future migration as opposed to a single serialized Hash.

Another catch I've personally experienced when using a serialized Hash is that you have to be careful that the serialized data you're storing isn't larger than what the DB text field can hold. You can easily end up with missing or corrupted data if you aren't careful. For example, using the SerializedProfile class & table you described, you could cause this behavior:

```
profile = SerializedProfile.create(:settings=>{})
100.times{ |i| profile.settings[i] = "A value" }
profile.save!
profile.reload
profile.settings.class #=> Hash
profile.settings.size #=> 100

5000.times{ |i| profile.settings[i] = "A value" }
profile.save!
profile.reload
profile.settings.class #=> String
profile.settings.size #=> 65535
```

All that code to say, be aware of your DB limits or your serialized data will be clipped the next time it's retrieved and ActiveRecord won't be able to re-serialize it.

For those of you that do want to use a Serialized Hash, go for it! I think it has potential to work well in some cases. I stumbled across the [activerecord-attribute-fakers plugin](https://github.com/animoto/activerecord-attribute-fakers) which seems like a good fit.