# How to store hash in session in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm looking for a way to serialize a hash so it can be stored in a Sinatra flash session. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: This might be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697650/pros-cons-of-storing-serialized-hash-vs-key-value-database-object-in-activerecor Sorry if not.

Comment: flash as adobe flash, or the rails flash object? And session as a rails session, or just some way of communication?

Comment: @Dutow Sinatra flash, not Rails. @TriVuong What are you using for your session storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialize your Hash to a JSON or YAML string and store that. This assumes that you don't have anything crazy in your Hash like a lambda or a Thread that cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to read this for ideas:

http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/

Personally, I use json for most of my client-facing objects that come from ruby.